# How to parse this into a dictionary VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I'm working on a project and I'm wondering how I would go about parsing a line like this:

```
oDesign.ChangeProperty Array("NAME:AllTabs", Array("NAME:LocalVariableTab", Array("NAME:PropServers", "LocalVariables"), Array("NAME:NewProps", Array("NAME:antipad", "PropType:=", "VariableProp", "UserDef:=", true, "Value:=", "40mil")), Array("NAME:ChangedProps", Array("NAME:antipad", "Hidden:=", false))))
```

into something like this:

```
oDesign.ChangeProperty(
[
    "NAME:AllTabs",
    [
        "NAME:LocalVariableTab",
        [
            "NAME:PropServers", 
            "LocalVariables"
        ],
        [
            "NAME:NewProps",
            [
                "NAME:antipad",
                "PropType:="        , "VariableProp",
                "UserDef:="     , True,
                "Value:="       , "40mil"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "NAME:ChangedProps",
            [
                "NAME:antipad",
                "Hidden:="      , False,
                "Value:="       , "40mil"
            ]
        ]
    ]
])
```

I was thinking about using dictionaries, but I'm not sure how to do this with VBA.

Also, suggestions about indentation are appreciated. I was thinking about using stacks, but I'm sure there are easier ways to do it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "parse into" *??what??*: tree, graph, etc.?

Comment: Which is the goal? The second code is not correct VBA syntax. What are you trying to achieve? Where does the VBA-Array comes from? Why in this format?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to get JSON from this kind of VBA arrays, then this could be a approach:

```
Sub test()
 arr = Array("NAME:AllTabs", Array("NAME:LocalVariableTab", Array("NAME:PropServers", "LocalVariables"), Array("NAME:NewProps", Array("NAME:antipad", "PropType:=", "VariableProp", "UserDef:=", True, "Value:=", "40mil")), Array("NAME:ChangedProps", Array("NAME:antipad", "Hidden:=", False))))
 sJSON = "[" & recursiveVBAArrayToJSON(arr, "") & vbLf & "]"
 MsgBox sJSON
End Sub

Function recursiveVBAArrayToJSON(arr As Variant, res As String) As String
 For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
  If TypeName(arr(i)) = "Variant()" Then
   res = res & vbLf & "["
   res = recursiveVBAArrayToJSON(arr(i), res)
   res = res & vbLf & "]" & IIf(i <> UBound(arr), ",", "")
  Else
   res = res & vbLf & """" & arr(i) & """" & IIf(i <> UBound(arr), ",", "")
  End If
 Next
 recursiveVBAArrayToJSON = res
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Axel created his solution faster than I created mine and I do not normally post rival solutions unless I think earlier solutions are faulty.  Axel's solution does not look faulty but he has not handled indenting (which you specifically mention as important) nor does he concatenate "Xxxx=" with the value.  I also think Axel is correct to use recursion rather than collections.  However, I decided to post this answer as a possibly interesting alternative.

You can do little with Excel VBA without using the inbuilt collections.  However, I rarely have user collections or dictionaries because I do not normally tackle problems big enough to need them in VBA.  This requirement looked simple so I thought I would treat it as a training exercise.

My understanding of dictionaries is that a key is compulsory.  There are no obvious keys so I have used collections.

The code below is basic.  I have performed the minimum of validation and I am sure I could have handled the output in a more elegant manner.  I have limited myself to “can it be done?”

I have placed your string in cell A1 of worksheet “Sheet1” as the easiest way of making it available to the macros.

My output does not include the trailing “"Value:="  ,   "40mil"” because it is not in the input string.

I have handled indenting consistently and I have used a constant so you can easily change the number of spaces.  The number of spaces between strings and comma does not seem consistent in your required output so I have made little attempt to match it.  However, I see that as a minor detail; the answer to you question is “Yes, your string can be parsed and converted to the output you desire.”

```
Option Explicit
Enum EVT
  DCP
  ArrayOpen
  ArrayClose
  Comma
  Str
  BoolTrue
  BoolFalse
End Enum
Sub Control()

  Dim InxOutput As Long
  Dim InxToken As Long
  Dim Output As New Collection
  Dim StrToParse As String
  Dim Tokens As New Collection

  StrToParse = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value

  Call Parse(StrToParse, Tokens)

  For InxToken = 1 To Tokens.Count
    Debug.Print Tokens.Item(InxToken)
  Next

  Call CreateOutput(Tokens, Output)

  For InxOutput = 1 To Output.Count
    Debug.Print Output.Item(InxOutput)
  Next

  Set Tokens = Nothing
  Set Output = Nothing

End Sub
Sub Parse(ByVal Str As String, ByRef Tokens As Collection)

  ' Str is a string such as: oDesign.ChangeProperty Array("NAME:AllTabs", ...
  ' On entry, Token must be an empty collection.
  ' The routine parses Str and creates tokens in Tokens of the form:
  '   nn¬mm¬xxxxx
  ' where:
  '  * nn is the level of the token.  1 for the outer token, oDesign.ChangeProperty,
  '    and 2, 3 and so on for each nested array or array element
  '  * ¬ is a separator
  '  * mm is a enumerator defined by Enum EVT:
  '     * Enum       Indicated token
  '     * DCP        oDesign.ChangeProperty
  '     * ArrayOpen  Array(
  '     * ArrayClose )
  '     * Comma      ,
  '     * Str        Quoted string
  '     * BoolTrue   true
  '     * BoolFalse  false
  '  * xxxxx with its preceding ¬ is only present for a quoted string. The value
  '    of xxxxx is the quoted string without the quotes.

  Dim LevelCrnt As Long
  Dim PosStrCrnt As Long
  Dim PosStrQuote As Long

  PosStrCrnt = 1
  LevelCrnt = 1

  If Mid(Str, PosStrCrnt, 22) <> "oDesign.ChangeProperty" Then
    Debug.Assert False
    ' String does not start as expected
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Tokens.Add LevelCrnt & "¬" & EVT.DCP
  LevelCrnt = LevelCrnt + 1

  PosStrCrnt = PosStrCrnt + 22

  Do While PosStrCrnt < Len(Str)
    If Mid(Str, PosStrCrnt, 1) = " " Then
      ' Step over space
      PosStrCrnt = PosStrCrnt + 1
    ElseIf Mid(Str, PosStrCrnt, 1) = "," Then
      ' Comma
      Tokens.Add LevelCrnt & "¬" & EVT.Comma
      PosStrCrnt = PosStrCrnt + 1
    ElseIf Mid(Str, PosStrCrnt, 1) = ")" Then
      ' End of array
      LevelCrnt = LevelCrnt - 1
      Tokens.Add LevelCrnt & "¬" & EVT.ArrayClose
      PosStrCrnt = PosStrCrnt + 1
    ElseIf Mid(Str, PosStrCrnt, 6) = "Array(" Then
      ' Start of array
      Tokens.Add LevelCrnt & "¬" & EVT.ArrayOpen
      LevelCrnt = LevelCrnt + 1
      PosStrCrnt = PosStrCrnt + 6
    ElseIf Mid(Str, PosStrCrnt, 1) = """" Then
      ' Quoted string
      PosStrCrnt = PosStrCrnt + 1
      PosStrQuote = InStr(PosStrCrnt, Str, """")
      If PosStrQuote = 0 Then
        ' Unterminated string
        Debug.Assert False
        Exit Sub
      End If
      Tokens.Add LevelCrnt & "¬" & EVT.Str & "¬" & Mid(Str, PosStrCrnt, PosStrQuote - PosStrCrnt)
      PosStrCrnt = PosStrQuote + 1
    ElseIf Mid(Str, PosStrCrnt, 4) = "true" Then
      Tokens.Add LevelCrnt & "¬" & EVT.BoolTrue
      PosStrCrnt = PosStrCrnt + 4
    ElseIf Mid(Str, PosStrCrnt, 5) = "false" Then
      Tokens.Add LevelCrnt & "¬" & EVT.BoolFalse
      PosStrCrnt = PosStrCrnt + 5
    Else
      ' Unexpected token
      Debug.Print PosStrCrnt & ": " & Mid(Str, PosStrCrnt, 20)
      Debug.Assert False

      Exit Sub
    End If

  Loop

End Sub
Sub CreateOutput(ByRef Tokens As Collection, ByRef Output As Collection)

  ' Tokens is a collection of tokens created by Parse
  ' On entry. Output is an empty collection
  ' On exit, Output is an human readable version of Tokens

  ' The routine processes the contents in sequence.

  Dim ContinuePending As Boolean
  Dim EVTCrnt As Long
  Dim InxToken As Long
  Dim InxPart As Long
  Dim LevelCrnt As Long
  Dim Part() As String
  Dim Pending As String

  Const SpacesPerLevel As Long = 4

  Pending = ""
  ContinuePending = False

  For InxToken = 1 To Tokens.Count

    ' Split token into components
    Part = Split(Tokens.Item(InxToken), "¬")
    LevelCrnt = Val(Part(0))
    EVTCrnt = Val(Part(1))

    Select Case EVTCrnt
      Case EVT.DCP
        Debug.Assert LevelCrnt = 1
        ' No indent for level 1
        Output.Add ("oDesign.ChangeProperty(")
      Case EVT.ArrayOpen
        ' Ouput [ in line with array's parent
        Output.Add (Space((LevelCrnt - 2) * SpacesPerLevel) & "[")
      Case EVT.ArrayClose
        If Pending <> "" Then
          ' The final contents of this array have not been output
          Output.Add (Space((LevelCrnt - 1) * SpacesPerLevel) & Pending)
          Pending = ""
        End If
        ' Ouput ] or ]) in line with array's parent
        If InxToken = Tokens.Count Then
          ' This is the close of the final array. Include closing bracket
          Output.Add ("])")
        Else
          ' This may be a nested array with a following comma
          Pending = "]"
        End If
      Case EVT.Comma
        ' Add to Pending
        Pending = Pending & ","
        If Not ContinuePending Then
          ' The next string is not to be added to Pending so output
          Output.Add (Space((LevelCrnt - 2) * SpacesPerLevel) & Pending)
          Pending = ""
        End If
      Case EVT.Str
        If Pending <> "" Then
          ' This string is to be appended to previous token
          Pending = Pending & "   """ & Part(2) & """"
        Else
          ' This is a new string
          Pending = """" & Part(2) & """"
        End If
        If Right(Part(2), 2) = ":=" Then
          ' The next string is to be appended to this one
          ContinuePending = True
          ' Add some spaces before comma
          Pending = Pending & "  "
        Else
          ContinuePending = False
          ' Don't output in case comma is to be appended
        End If
      Case BoolTrue
        If Pending <> "" Then
          ' This string is to be appended to previous token
          Pending = Pending & "   ""True"""
        Else
          ' This is a new string
          Pending = """True"""
        End If
        ' True cannot be continued but there may be a following comma
        ContinuePending = False
      Case BoolFalse
        If Pending <> "" Then
          ' This string is to be appended to previous token
          Pending = Pending & "   ""False"""
        Else
          ' This is a new string
          Pending = """False"""
        End If
        ' False cannot be continued but there may be a following comma
        ContinuePending = False
    End Select

  Next

  If Pending <> "" Then
    ' Final output
    Output.Add Pending
    Pending = ""
  End If

End Sub
```